# 4096 bit key generation on OpenPGP card

Tags: gnupg, smartcard, openpgp

What is the corresponding command to create a 4096 bit RSA key on an OpenPGP card via `gpg(2) --card-edit`? The documentation just indicates `--algo=`. I tried `RSA`with different values like 3072 and 4096 - but everything results in 2048 bit keys.

Using Kleopatra I was able to generate 3072 bit keys on the card.

I am using OpenPGP Cards V3.3, gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27 and a ReinerSCT comfort card reader with latest driver from Ubuntu repository. Copying 4096 bit to the card is possible. I remember that several years ago there has been an issue to some card readers limiting the key length when creating keys directly on the card but I cannot find any current specifications.